# How can make dynamic control in Angular 6 HTML Page?

Tags: angular6

I am new in Angular 6 and using Type Script. I want to print 3 item per row. How can do this ?

I am trying like this but print as single row

```
<tr>
<td *ngFor="let column of columnList">
{{column.column_name}}
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='column.column_value' class='text' placeholder="Add {{column.column_name}}" />
</td>
</tr>
```

I am trying another way like:

```
**inside .ts file:-
htmlStr = "<input type='text' />"**
**using inside .html file:-
<div [innerHTML]="htmlStr"></div>**
```

But input control not be rendered. Why I am not understand exactly what is the issue in rendering else print in console.log already.

Comment: it's hard to understand what is your problem. Please post your data structure (columnList var) and describe what you obtain with your code

Comment: I mention everything . Please check this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrM8r.png